# Set everyday local notification for 3 months

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I am working on an iOS application. My requirement is to set a local notification every morning. I want to repeat the local notification every day with different messages/alertBody.I know we can set max 64 local notifications. But what if the user does not open the app for 2 months?

Comment: If the user hasn't opened your app after two months of daily notifications, perhaps your app isn't providing enough compelling utility to the user. An app should *do something useful*.

Comment: @Caleb Totally agree with you. Thanks